# DataGridView duplicating everytime I press refresh button vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm trying to Refresh my DataGridView1. I think I have to add a clear function because it keeps duplicating the data every time I press my refresh button. I'm not using a data source for DataGridView1.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Coding:

```
    Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
    Refreshdata()
End Sub

Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectDatabase2003.mdb")
Dim DS As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim DA As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim tables As DataTableCollection = DS.Tables
Dim source1 As New BindingSource()

Private Sub Refreshdata()
    DA = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Risk_Register", myConnection)
    DA.Fill(DS, "Risk_Register")
    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.Refresh()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Fill` method can duplicate rows,

> The Fill operation adds the rows to the specified destination
> DataTable object in the DataSet, creating the DataTable object if it
> does not already exist. When you create a DataTable object, the Fill
> operation ordinarily creates only column name metadata. However, if
> the MissingSchemaAction property is set to AddWithKey, appropriate
> primary keys and constraints are also created.
>
> If primary key information is present, any duplicate rows are
> reconciled and only appear one time in the DataTable that corresponds
> to the DataSet. Primary key information may be set either through
> FillSchema, by specifying the PrimaryKey property of the DataTable, or
> by setting the MissingSchemaAction property to AddWithKey.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.7

Ensure PK is defined on the target table. Alternatively clear the table before filling but take care of FKs and relations the table takes part in, if any.

Comment: I tried to clear the DataGridView1 before filling but that isn't working for me either using DataGridView1.Rows.Clear(). Im not using a datasource and yeah I have defined a PK in the table. Its only duplicating the table on the vb.net app but not my Access database.

Comment: I get an error saying 'Cannot clear the list'

Comment: Clear  DataTable, not DataGridView

Comment: Would I add this just before  Refreshdata()? Also what is the formatting for clearing DataTable as I'v never used this before?

Comment: How would I be able to do this in my code?

Comment: Provided this is the only point of data retrieval populating DS you can clear entire DS. `DS.Clear()` then `DA.Fill(DS, ...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much Serg, this fixed the issue. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I tried but it doesn't let me, I think because its a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call the Update method available under the adapter.

Comment: Sorry but don't understand what you mean.